# Truncate first five digits of postal zip codes

Tags: validation-rule, field-update

On the `Account` object I have a field called `Postal Zip Code`. If `Postal Zip Code` is more than 5 characters long (e.g. `"12345678"`), I have to truncate to 5 characters (e.g. `"12345"`). How can I do so using `Validation Rules`?

Comment: you cannot use validation rule to update field values. it has to be either workflow field update or a process builder. validation rules are used to prevent / stop entering incorrect values.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you want to take the first 5 digits from the zipcode field to use in the validation rule, you can use the LEFT function to do that. As per the [Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=0&language=en_US), the `LEFT(text, num_chars)` function *Returns the specified number of characters from the beginning of a text string.*

```
TRIM(LEFT(zipcode, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the formula from above answer (Trim(Left(BillingPostalCode,5)) in a formula field, then use a flow or process builder to grab the value from the formula field and plug it into the zipcode field.  You definitely can not use validation rules to update fields.